# How to fixed receiving port in tcp client mode?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, mfc

Normally, when tcp client is connected to tcp server, it has one receive port random. So I want to know any way to fixed this port in tcp client (windows socket, mfc).

Answer (score 0):

You can call [Create()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h61d04c.aspx) to specify a port before calling [Connect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxt965kz.aspx):

```
CSocket yourSocket;
yourSocket.Create(sourcePort);
yourSocket.Connect(targetHost, targetPort);
```

Comment: @Frederic Hamidi ,,is there any equivalent method in java for this??